# Elasticsearch and Kibana docker containers communication with SSL protocol

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, ssl, docker-compose, kibana

this is my docker-compose

```
version: "3.0"
services:
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: es-container
    image: elasticsearch:8.7.0
    environment:
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/kibana.crt
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.key=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/kibana.key
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificateAuthorities=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/kibana.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/kibana.key
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificateAuthorities=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/ca.crt
    
    volumes:
      - ./certs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
  kibana:
    container_name: kb-container
    image: kibana:8.7.0
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=https://es-container:9200
      - ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_CERTIFICATEAUTHORITIES=/usr/share/kibana/config/certs/ca.crt
      - ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_CERTIFICATE=/usr/share/kibana/config/certs/kibana.crt
      - ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_KEY=/usr/share/kibana/config/certs/kibana.key
    volumes:
      - ./certs:/usr/share/kibana/config/certs
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
```

elasticsearch container returns this logs before exiting

> es-container  | ERROR: Elasticsearch did not exit normally - check the
> logs at /usr/share/elasticsearch/logs/docker-cluster.log es-container
> |  es-container  | ERROR: Elasticsearch exited unexpectedly

i am trying to connect elasticsearch and kibana containers using ssl protocol to secure the communication between them

Comment: There should be an other error log right before the one you posted. Usually it's not very readable but it should give you more informations. You can use `docker logs es-container` to see it, or maybe even `docker logs es-container|grep ERROR`